# Problema imprimir variables creadas dinámicamente

Tags: php

Tengo un **ejemplo de como crear variables dinámicamente en PHP**, y observo un comportamiento extraño al imprimirlas. Tan pronto salen los nombres de las frutas como igual numero de ceros. He probado, un par de entornos de ejecución y de versiones de PHP con los mismos resultados.
¿Qué se me escapa?

```
<?php

//Creación dinámica de variables

$arr = [
    "uva",
    "pera",
    "melón",
    "fresa"
];

$cont = 0;
foreach ( $arr as $value ) {

    $cont++;
    ${ "fruta" . $cont } = $value;
}

//Imprimirlas

for ( $i=1; $i <= $cont; $i++ ) {

    $x = ${ "fruta" . $i };

    //echo $x;
    //echo $x + "<br>";
    echo ( $x );
    echo ( $x + "<br>" );
}

?>
```

Comment: puedes mostrar el resultado que te imprime?

Comment: Se puede probar el código en:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68da89c305d39e1ea2d822e63ba4a73a071b4622

Comment: @Orici es recomendable que el código y los datos necesarios se encuentren aquí y no en un link externo, ya que ese tipo de links tienden a desaparecer y las preguntan pierden sentido en el futuro.

Answer (score 3):

el problema parece estar en la última linea no debería ser

```
echo ( $x + "<br>" );
```

sino

```
echo ( $x . "<br>" );
```

Las concatenaciones son con `.` en PHP

Comment: Cierto.
Es que llevo un tiempo liado con Java.

Comment: no hay problema amigo, si te sirvió marcarlo como respuesta por favor

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar en php se hace a través de un punto (.), el fallo está en la última linea:

`echo ( $x + "<br>" );`

Has concatenado con el signo "+", esto es válido en la mayoría de lenguajes, pero No en php, por lo que debes usar un punto (.), por tanto debería quedar así:

```
echo ( $x."<br>" );
```

saludos!!

Comment: Buenas Luis. Al ser nuevo buscas el ganar reputacion pero intenta no publicar respuestas identicas a las ya posteadas. Un saludo!